# req.on('end fired but not req.on('data

Tags: node.js

My `Nodejs` `req.on('data')` not trigger, but `req.on('end')` works. I'm learning `Nodejs` and I don't know how to fix it.

**My `Nodejs` file:**

```
let routes = {
    'GET': {
            '/': (req,res) => {
                fs.readFile('./public/index.html', (err, html) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
                    res.write(html);
                    res.end();
                });
            }
    },
    'POST': {
            '/api/login': (req, res) => {
                let body = '';
                req.on('data', data => {
                    console.log('req data fired!');
                    body += data;
                });

                req.on('end', () => {
                    console.log('req end fired!')
                    res.end();
                })
            }
    }
}

function router(req, res) {
    let baseURL = url.parse(req.url, true);
    let resolveRoute = routes[req.method][baseURL.pathname];
    if(resolveRoute != undefined) {
        resolveRoute(req, res);
    }
}


http.createServer(router).listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running in port 3000'));
```

How to fix the `req.on('data')` triggering?

Comment: Do you realize that you can't use this `routes` data structure as you shown for more than a single GET and a single POST route because you can't specify duplicate entries with the same method.  Not what you asked about, but this data structure won't really work for any sort of real application.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is some data on the POST request?  This would be data that exists in the http request AFTER the headers are done.  Can you show us exactly what the http request looks like that you're testing?

Comment: The only way I could reproduce the problem was when there was no actual data in the POST request.  I created that problem accidentally by not providing a `name` attribute on any of my form elements, but there are lots of ways that could happen.  Once I made sure there was some data in the POST body, I always get the `data` event you are asking about.  So, I think you need to look at the source of the POST request and see if there is actually any body to the POST request.  If not, there's no data to read so you will just get the `end` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `data` event doesn't fire, but the `end` event does, then it's because there is no actual body data in the POST request.

With your exact code, the only way I could reproduce what you describe is when the POST body was empty and there was no data there to read.  If, for example, you are submitting a form in the browser and there are no elements in the form with a `name` attribute, no data will be sent with the request.

As soon as I made sure there was some data in the POST request, then the `data` event fires and it presents a Buffer with the data in it.

Comment: Thank you! It works after i put name attribute on input tag